# summarise column and add it's common values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe something like this and my end goal is to make a bar chart.
Here is the data frame.

```
a   5
a   7
b   23
b   12
c   21
c   21
c   27
```

I want to summarize the dataframe with the first column but want to add the values of the 2nd column and make a bar chart for the values of 2nd column. The resulting data frame should be :

```
a   12
b   35
c   69
```

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
d %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise(V2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + geom_col()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be pretty straightforward. Let me know if this helps.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    
    #Converting your values into a dataframe
    
    data <- data.frame("Key" = c("a","a","b","b","c","c","c"), "Value" = c(5,7,23,12,21,21,27))
    
    data <- data %>%
      group_by(Key) %>%
      summarise(Value = sum(Value))
    
    
    #Plot
    ggplot(data, aes(x=Key, y=Value))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple base R option using `barplot` + `aggregate`

```
barplot(SumValue ~ ., aggregate(cbind(SumValue = Value) ~ ., df, sum))
```

[image]